# Error Heatmap plugin QGIS 3.2.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, heat-map

My questions is about heatmap plugin in QGIS 3.2.0

I have my data in CRTM05 projection, it´s a metric projection to Costa Rica based in WGS84 Datum.

When I try to run the Heatmap plugin, the running show this:

> "Processing algorithm… Algorithm 'Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)'
>   starting… Input parameters: { 'DECAY' : 0, 'INPUT' :
>   '/Users/robertovargasmasis/Desktop/Taller SIG 2018 CeU
>   Neily/ejemplo_mapadecalor/puntos_crtm05.shp', 'KERNEL' : 0, 'OUTPUT' :
>   '/var/folders/2z/fsqk6cy931d8r3c97qhc5gcr0000gn/T/processing_5bcc93e95ed54cd8b7e647b933ecf4e1/94fc27fbde38406eabee152a81d702aa/OUTPUT.tif',
>   'OUTPUT_VALUE' : 0, 'PIXEL_SIZE' : 0.1, 'RADIUS' : 100, 'RADIUS_FIELD'
>   : None, 'WEIGHT_FIELD' : None }
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Heatmap.py",
>   line 215, in processAlgorithm self.tr('Could not create destination
>   layer'))
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create destination layer
>
> Execution failed after 0.03 seconds
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'Heatmap (Kernel Density
>   Estimation)' finished"

Someone have had this problem? 
How to fix it?

Comment: I see you have spaces in the path to your input file. Copy the shapefile(s) to a folder with no spaces in its name, to see if that works (maybe something like /Desktop/Taller_SIG_2018....") . Sometimes the filename isn't quoted properly, when that happens , spaces in file paths can break things.

Comment: I have had the same problem, though I am using SAD6996 projection.
The text seems to be the same: Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DECAY' : 0, 'INPUT' : '/Users/martimfurtado/Dropbox/EQUIPE/Martim/layers/SAD69-96_SHP_TEMA_-_SAUDE_UBS-POSTO_DE_SAUDE-CENTRO_DE_SAUDE.shp', 'KERNEL' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : '/var/folders/wz/0jmtyzqj2bsd_31hv3hkl3vc0000gn/T/processing_21db7899ba1641c081f8cc3781124c73/08461555934740468669e3fb199d4f95/OUTPUT.tif', 'OUTPUT_VALUE' : 0, 'PIXEL_SIZE' : 0.1, 'RADIUS' : 100, 'RADIUS_FIELD' : None, 'WEIGHT_FIELD' :

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144209)

Comment: I get the same problem, with the same error with QGIS 3.2.3 - "Could not create destination layer" - this is true even if explicit output path with no spaces is supplied.

Comment: I posted a bug report for this: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20105

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the pixel size. The default value may be too small, thus resulting in an overly large file. The default was 0.1, I changed it to 5 and the heatmap worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Damini Jain answered in [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293992/heatmap-processing-exception-in-qgis-3-2)

1. Right click on your layer.
2. Select Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog, switch to the Symbology tab
4. Select heatmap